# Space characters in text citations after page

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I am using `biblatex` for my citations.

To cite I use `\citep[123]{author}`.

This gets `(Lastname, 2010, p.____5)`

Reading the `biblatex` documentation I am overwhelmed. I found how to compress ranges how to have several p's there in case of several citations. But how do I change the space after "p." to a `\,`?

Answer (score 7):

```
\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbthinspace}
```

See sections 4.6.4 (the `\mkpageprefix` paragraphs)  and 4.7.4 of the `biblatex` manual for details.