# biblatex: Remove space between p. and page number in postnote

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I change a command like `\textcite[][8]{example}` to display `p.8` rather than `p.~8` in the text, while printing the postnote as-is if it does not resemble a page number.

I tried using `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\pno#1}`  after looking at section 3.13.3 in the biblatex manual, but -- unsurprisingly -- it does not work when the postnote is not a page:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
  title   = {Some things I did},
  year    = {2014},
  journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\pno#1}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello\textcite[][8]{example}. But \textcite[][Table~5]{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Space characters in text citations after page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49260/35864), [How to remove the space between “pp.” and the page numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140985/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave the standard definition for `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}` and add

```
\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{}
```

But please be warned that omitting the space between the "p."/"pp." and page number looks extremely odd (I would even say terrible) and is not the norm in any language I know.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite[][8]{sigfridsson} ipsum \textcite[][Table~5]{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree that it is terrible.

Comment: @Hugh: A thin unbreakable space would probably look better (`\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\,}`).